# how to find name of current wordpress user in non-wp page

Tags: wordpress

I link from WP to a non-wp page. How can I find the username of the person that logged into wp? This doesn't work.

```
  <?php 
    require_once("../members/wordpress/wp-load.php");


if(is_user_logged_in())
{
    echo '<br />User Logged in ok<br />';
    echo 'User ID is: '.$user_ID.'<br />';
    echo 'User login is: '.$current_user->user_login.'<br />';
}
else
    echo 'No user is logged in<br/>';
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working well.

In Wordpress I saved a cookie. Then in a non-wordpress page, before the 
DOCTYPE line, I placed this code:

```
<?php
    session_start();   
    $name =  $_SESSION['member_name'];
    if ($name == '') {
      header('Location: searchObits.php'); 
      exit;
    } else {  $_SESSION["ismember"] = "member";  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
wp_get_current_user();
```

Documentation states that it is a wrapper of get_currentuserinfo().

So, try this;

```
<?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
        // Not logged in.
    } else {
        // Logged in.
    }
?>
```

If it does not work since you are on a non-wp page. Try replacing wp_get_current_user() with get_currentuserinfo().

Comment: If by non-Wordpress page you mean a page being served that is not coming from a WordPress install then the WP functions are not going to work.

Comment: The asker, stated that it is a non-wp page, i understood it same way as you did. Thus, i provided another solution (get_currentuserinfo()) php function.

Comment: I am on a non-wp page. I placed the following at the beginning of that page

Comment: I am on a non-wp page via a Custom Link. It was also necessary to put  require_once("../wordpress/wp-load.php"); at the beginning, in order to execute the get_currentuserinfo. No matter what I've tried, the IF statement always goes to the "not logged in" code.

Comment: Did you use the if statement i provided, or the one you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Your non-wp page is not in WP folder, so it won't have access to WP cookie. If you want WP cookie to be seen by php script located outside of your WP folder, need to define `COOKIEPATH` to point to common parent folder of your php script & your wp folder, or just point it to root folder.
Put the following line in your wp-config.php:

```
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
```

PS: Also your non-wp page should be served from the same domain as WP.